# show users connected to windows telnet server

Tags: windows-server-2003, telnet

I can't believe how bad I am at googling windows stuff. How can I list the users connected via telnet to a windows machine? It seems such a basic question, yet I couldn't find a answer. X-(

Also, after I list the users, is there a way to kill a specific user's connection? how?

I'm on a windows server 2003.

Comment: In before "ZOMG TELNET" comments!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command [`tlntadmn -s`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772315(v=ws.10).aspx)  will list information about the current Telnet sessions. This will display something like the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>tlntadmn -s
1 telnet session(s)

ID    Domain     UserName      Client     LogonDate LogonTime   IdleTime
                                                               (hh:mm:ss)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2396  HORACE     jscott        ::1        7/7/2014 10:02:43 PM  0:01:04
```

You can end the session using [`tlntadmn -k ID`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725698(v=ws.10).aspx). Using the above example `tlntadmn -k 2396`.  `tlntadmn -k all` to terminate all telnet sessions.